# Spring boot controller is not able to serialize response

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

This is my controller function to add User

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addUser(Users user) {
        users.clear();
        users.add(user);
        ServiceResponse<Users> response = new ServiceResponse<Users>("success", users);
        return new ResponseEntity(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Below is ServiceResponse class

```
public class ServiceResponse<T> {

    private String status;
    private List<T> data;

    public ServiceResponse(String status, List<T> data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And finally below given is my ajax request function

```
function ajaxPost() {
    // DO POST
    $.ajax(
 document.location.origin+"/users/add",{
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#userForm").serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
            if (result!=null) {
                $("#postResultDiv").html(
                    "" + result.data.userName
                    + "Post Successfully! <br>"
                    + "---> Congrats !!" + "</p>");
            } else {
                $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
            }
            console.log(result);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert("Error!")
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
```

The request hits the controller as expected, however server responds with status 500. I guess this has something to do with serialization of response. I tried returning User object in ResponseEntity and it works perfectly fine. What is the possible cause of issue here?

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding getter methods for the ServiceResponse fields:

```
public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public List<T> getData() {
    return this.data;
}
```